# Typeorm & Typescript EntityMetadataNotFoundError On Compiled Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typeorm, tsc

i'm trying to build a backend with nodejs & express & typeorm using typescript.
I have a problem that when i run application with `nodemon` it's work like intended. But when i start with `node app.js` on compiled javascript files and send request to any end point it's givin me the error `EntityMetadataNotFoundError`. How can i get pass this issue ?

`ormconfig.json`

```json
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "",
    "entities": [
        "dist/src/entity/**/*.js",
        "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "dist/src/migration/**/*.js",
        "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js",
        "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
    }
}
```

i don't know if needed but here is `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6",
         "es7",
         "es2015",
         "es2016",
         "es2017",
         "es2018",
         "esnext"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
   }
}
```

my build script is `tsc --project .`

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,i figured out. `tsc --project .` command not copying the `ormconfig.json` file to `dist` directory. I changed `tsconfig.json`
and it works now!

I added `include` and `resolveJsonModule` properties.

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6",
         "es7",
         "es2015",
         "es2016",
         "es2017",
         "es2018",
         "esnext"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
   },
   "include": [
      "ormconfig.json"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running in to the same issue with **typeorm:"0.35"**, which doesn't use ormconfig.json anymore.

In my case the solution was to add the path to the entities in the build folder, such as this "**entities: ["build/entity/*.js"]**" instead of the development path "**entities: ["src/entity/*.ts"]**"
Note the js vs ts, and the build vs src.